# Symfony2: EventSubscriber yields Date error

Tags: forms, events, symfony

I've added an EventSubscriber to a form class so that a single template can be used for both add and edit of an entity.  Before adding the subscriber, a form would not throw an error for either add or edit.  After adding the subscriber, the following error occurs on editing when the conditions for adding the dateAdded field are met:

> Expected argument of type "\DateTime", "array" given

Otherwise, the EventSubscriber appears to perform as expected.

#### Subscriber

```
class AddV2FieldsSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface {

    private $factory;

    public function __construct(FormFactoryInterface $factory) {
        $this->factory = $factory;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
        return array(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA => 'preSetData');
    }

    public function preSetData(DataEvent $event) {
        $data = $event->getData();
        $form = $event->getForm();
        if (null === $data) {
            return;
        }
        // check if the client object is v1
        if (!$data->getId() || $data->getDateAdded()) {
            $date = new \DateTime();
            $form->add($this->factory->createNamed('dateAdded', 'date', $date, array(
                    'widget' => 'single_text',
                    'format' => 'MM/dd/yyyy',
                    'pattern' => '{{ year }}-{{ month }}-{{ day }}',
                    'years' => range(Date('Y'), Date('Y') - 5),
                    'required' => false,
                    'data' => date_create(),))
                    );
            $form->add($this->factory->createNamed('dob', 'dob_age')
                    );
            $form->add($this->factory->createNamed('sex', 'choice', array(
                    'choices' => array('Male' => 'Male', 'Female' => 'Female'),
                    'empty_value' => "Select a gender",
                    'required' => false))
                    );
        }
    }
}
```

#### The dateAdded field in its Entity:

```
/**
 * @var \DateTime $dateAdded
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="date_added", type="date", nullable=true)
 */
private $dateAdded;
```

#### Template snippet

```
    {% if form.dateAdded is defined %}
        {% include 'ManaClientBundle:Client:v2.html.twig' %}
    {% endif %}
```

Comment: The original error noted was due to the third parameter of the `createNamed()` function being an initial value, not the field options array as might be expected.  When an initial value is added, the error becomes `Notice: Array to string conversion in ...\ChoiceList.php line 457`

Answer (score 0):

Again, the answer is to pay attention to the third parameter of the `createNamed()` function.  In this case, I had to modify

```
$form->add($this->factory->createNamed('sex', 'choice', array(...
```

to read

```
$form->add($this->factory->createNamed('sex', 'choice', null, array(...
```